# A calendar that would display details of an object on each day of the year

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to display the details of an object from the database to the front-end calendar. The object changes its state everyday. I need to notify the user in the form of a calendar.
For example. I have a room object

```
Room(id: integer, room_type: string, price: float, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, beds_available: integer, total_beds: integer, gender: string, bathroom: string, availability: string)
```

I need to show changes in it's availablity, price etc. everyday. 
I tried using event calendar, these gems only work for events, i.e with a  start and an end date. Can anyone please suggest something that suits best to the above requirement?

Answer (score 1):

As per your explanation, I guess you need to simply need a way to list down the room entries on calendar. Also, I assume you already listed what all entries should be listed on what date and you dont want to use start_date and end_date.

If yes, then you can check with this gem: https://github.com/watu/table_builder

Comment: Thanks Kavita, I see this gem is no longer maintained. Could this be an issue as I am using Rails 4?

Comment: I am not sure on the compatibility with Rails 4 but yes it works fine with Rails 3. Need to verify or log an issue on the github repo for Rails 4

Comment: I implemented that in my application, works fine with Rails 4, however, it takes a table attribute as a date, whereas i need to provide a date for everyday.